# Introduction to Computer Hardware and Organization: Resources?

Tags: resources, hardware

I'm looking for a laymen's introduction to computer hardware and organization. Here are some of the topics I would like to cover.

> 1. Brief intro to electronics.
> 2. Gates and state machines, intro to register transfer and timing.
> 3. Basic CPU design. Control.
> 4. Microprogrammed CPU design.
> 5. Cache systems.
> 6. Memory hierarchy:registers, cache, RAM
> 7. Virtual memory organization.
> 8. Disk storage systems.
> 9. Internal busses-front side, memory, PCI
> 10. Internal busses for storage-IDE, SATA, SCSI
> 11. External busses-USB and firewire
> 12. Display systems and GPUs

I would prefer free resources online, but if nothing is available a book is fine as well. I have no background with hardware so an introductory text would be wonderful. Also I'm sorry if this isn't directly programming but I don't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned already Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software is a great book that covers the fundamentals.

Here are a couple of other books:

[Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605967)

[The Essentials of Computer Organization and Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076370444X)

[Upgrading and Repairing PCs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789736977)

Here's a good site:

[PC Architecture](http://www.karbosguide.com/books/pcarchitecture/start.htm)

Comment: "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach" is an excellent textbook. It taught me the bulk of what I know about how CPUs work.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the book ["Code"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319) by Charles Petzold.  It covers a lot of how the low level of a computer works from a layman's perspective.  Not everything on your list is included, but it will give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

[The Art of Electronics](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0521370957/ref=ase_penguintelecomin/102-8353601-4848123?v=glance&s=books%22The%20Art%20of%20Electronics%22) by Horowitz and Hill is a great one for hobbyist on electronics.

For computer architecture [Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/1558604286/ref=ase_penguintelecomin/102-8353601-4848123?v=glance&s=books/)

For RTL design [VHDL for Programmable Logic](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0201895730/ref=ase_penguintelecomin/102-8353601-4848123?v=glance&s=books)

Answer (score 0):

Tanenbaum's [Structured Computer Organization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131485210) was my intro into the 'levels' of computers. It's quite logical, approaching each level built on the previous.

I've often thought of doing a similar one, stretching from quantum physics through classical physics, electronics, integrated circuits, microcode, machine code, compilers, interpreters, VMs and so on, but I fear that would be about as possible as Knuth's 12-volume series. I hope he has a child to carry on the work :-).

Answer (score 0):

For computer architecture, this books is really good

[Parallel Computer Organization and Design](http://www.cambridge.org/ca/academic/subjects/engineering/computer-engineering/parallel-computer-organization-and-design)